# Новые изменения в коде, в командной работе с git

Tags: git

Я недавно начал работать с git в команде и у меня появился вопрос по этому поводу.

Предположим у нас есть ветка feature/search. В ней работает 2 разработчика. Один добавил изменение в эту ветку. Второй разроботчик работал со старой версией кода так как начал работу до того как первый разработчик сделал новые изменения. Получается перед выгрузкой новых изменений, второй разработчик должен выполнить git add ., git commit, git pull, git push.

Но git pull может совместить измениния так что будут ошибки в коде из за разного кода в общем и локальном репозитории

Я хочу понять как правильно вносить новые изменения в ветку с которой работают несколько разработчиков?

Comment: `git pull --rebase origin feature/search`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще обычно разработчики работают в разных ветках, а потом их мержат. Ну здесь ситуация будет такая же, второй разработчик будет исправлять конфликты.

Comment: Спасибо, подожду других ответов. Если их не будет помечу как решение

Comment: @Antonio Есть комментарий выше.